# How to destructure a constructor argument?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

In F# I can use pattern matching in a variety of places within the syntax.

For example:

```
// Given this type...
type SingleCaseUnion = | SingleCaseUnion of int

/// ...I can do this:
let destructureInFunc (SingleCaseUnion n) =
    printfn "%d" n

// ...and this:
type DestructureInMethod() =
    member t.M(SingleCaseUnion n) =
        printfn "%d" n
```

But I can't work out how to do this:

```
type DestructureInCtor(SingleCaseUnion n) =
    do printfn "%d" n

//  type DestructureInCtor(SingleCaseUnion n) =
//  ---------------------------------------^
//
// stdin(3,40): error FS0010: Unexpected identifier in type definition. Expected ')' or other token.
```

Do I have the syntax wrong, or does F# not support pattern matching in constructor parameters?

Comment: While it doesn't work for *primary* constructors, other (secondary) constructors allow it. *(reposted as comment since my answer became redundant.)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the [language spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/3.0/FSharpSpec-3.0-final.pdf) explicitly says no:

```
primary-constr-args : attributesopt accessopt (simple-pat, ... , simplepat)
simple-pat :
 | ident
 | simple-pat : type
```

As has been pointed out, secondary constructors are allowed pattern-matched parameters, but the difference with the primary constructor is each of the primary's parameters is both a function parameter *and* a private field declaration.

If F# were to allow pattern matching here, there would be some patterns that would break this one-parameter-one-field relationship.

```
type DestructureInCtor(SingleCaseUnion _) = 
    // doesn't declare a private field
```

or:

```
type DestructureInCtor((a:int, b:int)) = 
    // declares two private fields?
```

It's not inconceivable that this could work but I'm guessing the complexity of allowing pattern matching to be extended to providing field declarations outweighs the benefits.

Comment: Looking at section 8.6.1.3 of the spec, there doesn't seem to be a one-to-one parameter-field relationship. Parameters may remain local to the constructor depending on their usage, just like `let` bindings in the primary constructor. *(See the example where "The input y is used only during construction" in the spec)* Given that the rest of the primary constructor allows patterns, I don't understand why they would bring too much complexity in the parameter list.

Comment: @Vandroiy You're right that if a parameter is not used as a field, then no field is created. But these parameters *are* different to regular function parameters. That's why it would add complexity to allow pattern matching here and I'm suggesting that this wasn't on the language designers' priorities.

Comment: I'm comparing to let-bindings rather than function parameters. Why wouldn't `MyType (pattern) =` just be compiled as `MyType (a) = (newline) let pattern = a`? Doesn't seem to add much complexity at first glance.

Comment: @Vandroiy Parameters get compiled as member fields, not as let-bindings, and exposed through to .NET runtime.